# Can not force unwrap value of non-optional type 'XCUIElement'

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

I am using Xcode 7.2.1 and I have written some unit test cases for my code. My code compile and runs successfully but when I start tests, it fails.

Here is the code:

```
if let params = item["params"] {
     if let hours = params!["allowedHours"] {
            self.weekdays?.parseJSON(hours)
     }
}
```

I am getting "Can not force unwrap value of non-optional type 'XCUIElement'" on second line. This happens only when I am trying to execute test cases.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On the first line, you are unwrapping `params` through `if let`. Then, on the second line, you ask for `params` to be unwrapped again via `params!`, but it is already non-optional, thus it gets upset and throws that error, which says what I just did!

Comment: Thanks @sschel. I tried that but then it gives new issues 'value of optional type AnyObject? is not unwrapped, did you mean to use '!' or '?''

Comment: I just modified the first line like this: if let params = item["params"] as? [String : AnyObject] and removed unwrapping from param as you said, it worked! Thanks.